# how to style like this with CSS?

Tags: html, css

[image: badge in the top right]

html-

```
<div class="main">
  <span class="badge">Best Seller</span>
</div>
```

css-

```
    .main{
    position: relative;
  }

  .badge{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background-color: #2879FE;
  }
```

can anyone please show me what is the easiest way to do like this with CSS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic SO is not the place to ask for tutorials or give opinions of "the best way".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```css
.main {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px; right: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.badge {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    right: -10px;
    background-color: #2879FE;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.badge:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #2879FE;
    content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <span class="badge">Best Seller</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with pure CSS. I believe this is called a [CSS ribbon](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ribbon/)

I found a [pen by ds729](https://codepen.io/ds729/pen/bectB) and modified it to match your design a little but more.

```css
/* Reset */

html,
body,
div,
span,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
font,
img,
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #999;
}

h2 {
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

div#container {
  margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
  /* centered */
  width: 400px;
}

.bubble {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 350px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
  /* the stack order: displayed under ribbon rectangle (100) */
}

.rectangle {
  background: #2879fe;
  height: 50px;
  width: 30;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: -15px;
  top: -15px;
  float: left;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  z-index: 100;
  border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0
}

.rectangle h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 6px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

.triangle-l {
  border-color: transparent #2879fe transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
  /* displayed under bubble */
}

.info {
  padding: 60px 25px 35px 25px;
}

.info h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.info p {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 22px;
}

.info p a {
  color: #c4591e;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.info p a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="bubble">
    <div class="rectangle">
      <h2>Stack Overflow</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="triangle-l"></div>
    <div class="info">
      <h2>Hello</h2>
      <br />
      <p>
        <a href="#">This is pure CSS</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```